# Copy link-only answer to comment

Tags: discussion, support, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

While reviewing the low-quality answers, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046024/1771402). It is a link-only answer, but the link the answerer provided could be useful to others. Since the user doesn't have enough reputation, I think he has posted as answer. So can I copy the answer and post it as comment stating this was originally posted by other user?

Was it the right option or should I leave it and go? For those who couldn't see the answer here is a copy of that answer:

> Please refer this links [link 1](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html) & [link 2](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without exception, answers like this are low quality. That includes the [one from me](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5216726) which was voted for deletion via the review queue. And they also fit the *Not an answer* flag reason as well.

I give you credit for checking the links but your question does amuse me though - I think you need to reconsider what you think is "good" information. In your example above the links go to a couple of poorly formatted low quality blog posts. These do not add much value to the answer, so even if it was converted to a comment there would still be minimal value in it. Then compare that to the material I linked to in [my (previously deleted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960669/109702) - there is a massive difference.

I previously left someone else a comment suggesting that you edit posts as a way of salvaging links to good information. @MrLore has also suggested the same. While it is time consuming, the end result is far better if you can edit some context into the answer and turn a poor answer into an excellent one. That is, if the linked information is worth retaining. If it isn't worth keeping then recommend deletion, don't keep it around even as a comment.

Comment: The reason that made me to think it might be useful because the OP has commented "thank you " to the answerer.So i thought it might have helped OP.

Comment: It seems that many people are hesitant to " turn a poor answer into an excellent one" if its not their own, because then someone else will get all the nice reputation points.

Comment: @PlasmaHH true; althought (at least for me) the reason is different: I have been advised here on meta that it is better to post your own answer instead of radically changing someone else answer. Also it feels a bit weird to substantially change an answer which is not your own; and yes, I know everything here is more wiki-like and it should feel weird, but it still does.

Answer (score 2):

If you can be bothered, do it!

- It maintains the link while it's still around, in case its useful.
- Someone may spot the link and make a non-link-only answer out of it in the future.
- [Comments don't bump questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/245827).

Though, if you're in such a community-spirited mood, you could always edit the answer yourself to make it qualify as a good answer by making a brief answer out of the information contained in the link.

Comment: The problem is i dont have much idea about `ASP`. So i couldn't edit it.So i am going to leave it as it is. =(